# .NET Core in-memory Stream class which can use Memory<T> as storage

Tags: .net-core

I've been looking for a type that is analogous to the `MemoryStream` class, but uses a `Memory<T>` as storage medium instead of byte
The reason for this, is I want to create in-memory streams, whose data might come from either managed, or unmanaged source, and avoid the performance cost that comes with copying said data.
Does anyone know a type that derives from `System.Stream` and is applicable in this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've looked around the open issues on the corefx github, and it seems that such a type would be indeed be nice to have, and they have an open issue about it. However as things stand, such a thing is not yet available.